# Freertos + lwip+tinyUSB

Tags: c, config, freertos, lwip

I am trying to use LWIP with FreeRTOS and TinyUSB, but I am facing several issues in the configuration of LWIP (and possibly also in the configuration of FreeRTOS) to make them work together.

```
[build] /usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1/../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/pico.dir/pico-sdk/lib/lwip/src/core/tcp.c.obj: in function `tcp_init': [build] /home/wissem/Desktop/pico/pico-sdk/lib/lwip/src/core/tcp.c:204: undefined reference to `lwip_port_rand'
[build] /usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1/../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/pico.dir/pico-sdk/lib/lwip/src/core/udp.c.obj: in function `udp_init': [build] /home/wissem/Desktop/pico/pico-sdk/lib/lwip/src/core/udp.c:90: undefined reference to `lwip_port_rand'
[build] /usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1/../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/sACN.dir/pico-sdk/lib/lwip/src/core/ipv4/igmp.c.obj: in function `igmp_start_timer': [build] /home/wissem/Desktop/sACN/pico-sdk/lib/lwip/src/core/ipv4/igmp.c:695: undefined reference to `lwip_port_rand'
```

I use pico pi and pico-sdk.
Could someone help me with the configurations of both FreeRTOS and LWIP to work together?

Thank you.